# Install and run Tomcat 8 on Ubuntu 16.04 Error

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, installation

I need install tomcat 8 on Ubuntu 16.04.

I use [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Download tomcat from [this place](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi)

When I try to start tomcat, an error appears:

```
Job for tomcat.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status tomcat.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

What wrong?

Command `systemctl status tomcat.service` show this:

```
tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat 8 Servlet Container
    Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-03-22 15:26:39 CET; 4min 40s ago
    Process: 1578 ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

    Mar 22 15:26:39 vps635350 systemd[1]: Starting Apache Tomcat 8 Servlet Container...
    Mar 22 15:26:39 vps635350 systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=203
    Mar 22 15:26:39 vps635350 systemd[1]: Failed to start Apache Tomcat 8 Servlet Container.
    Mar 22 15:26:39 vps635350 systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Unit entered failed state.
    Mar 22 15:26:39 vps635350 systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I do not understand what is wrong. Already tried to change permissions on folders, but it does not work

`logs` folder is empty.

Comment: Probalbe cause: java not found.  See https://superuser.com/questions/944244/running-a-java-process-from-systemd

Comment: @Pino. Yes. I set JAVA_HOME and this error is gone. But tomcat still did not start

Comment: Does it now add exceptions to the logs folder?

Comment: @Selaron logs folder is empty